# Reference a window control in the code behind by building a string for the control name

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am trying to access some controls on a window in the code behind as I need to cycle through them to set values and properties. I have given the names of the controls that are the control type followed by sequential integers (i.e. `Label_1`, `Label_2`, etc). In VBA I have been able to do it by building a string that includes a variable for the name and using `Me.Controls`. For example:

```
Dim Count As Integer
For Count = 1 to 5
    Me.Controls("Label_" & Count).Caption = Count
Next Count
```

I have been unable to find an equivalent methodology to use for WPF VB.Net. I have tried several things with `VisualTreeHelper` but haven't gotten anything to work out. I have seen methods that would work using `VisualTreeHelper` that cycle through ALL of the controls in the window, but I want something that specifically targets certain controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find controls by their name, you can use the [`FrameworkElement.FindName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname?view=netcore-3.1) method in the code-behind of your `Window`, `UserControl` or on any other `FrameworkElement`.

```
public object FindName(string name);
```

This method will search recursively through child elements within the current element's [namescope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-namescopes?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).